# Calculated categories don't work in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have a `year`-template for my mediawiki installation and it contains the following snippet:

```
[[Category:{{#expr:{{#sub:{{PAGENAME}}|0|2}}+1}}th Century]]
```

If I'm using it on the page `1958` the category `20th Century` shows up at the bottom, but: The page does not show up on the category-page `20th Century`. If I explicitly add `[[Category:20th Century]]` to the page `1958` it shows up as expected.

Any idea, why?

Comment: What happends if you run the job queue?

Comment: The job queue runs every two hours and works well if I explicitly add `[[Category:20th Century]]` but not if I add the `year`-template.

Comment: What happens if you "hard code" the template content in the page?

Comment: What's the result of parsing that wikicode? E.g. what do you get at `Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&title=1958&text=%5B%5BCategory%3A%7B%7B%23expr%3A%7B%7B%23sub%3A%7B%7BPAGENAME%7D%7D%7C0%7C2%7D%7D%2B1%7D%7D20th%20Century%5D%5D&prop=categories%7Cparsewarnings%7Ctext%7Ccategorieshtml`?

Comment: Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/Qacik0Lp
Remark: The wiki is german, hence we're talking about `20. Jahrhundert` instead of `20th Century`.